# Active Admin Routing error uninitialized constant Admin::DashboardController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm getting the following error after updating ActiveAdmin:

on `http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin`

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant Admin::DashboardController
```

I tried moving my custom root and devise routes before ActiveActive routes.

My routes:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => "download#index"

  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

My rake routes:

```
                   root            /                                              download#index
       new_user_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)                         active_admin/devise/sessions#new
           user_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)                         active_admin/devise/sessions#create
   destroy_user_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)                        active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
          user_password POST       /admin/password(.:format)                      active_admin/devise/passwords#create
      new_user_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)                  active_admin/devise/passwords#new
     edit_user_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
                        PUT        /admin/password(.:format)                      active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                   root            /                                              dashboard#index
             admin_root            /admin(.:format)                               admin/dashboard#index
```

I've went through almost all the questions on stack, any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated!

**SOLUTION:**

Solved it by:

touch app/admin/dashboard.rb

and added code from:

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/generators/active_admin/install/templates/dashboard.rb

Comment: try putting `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` before `root :to => "download#index"`

Comment: that's how it was and it didn't work

Comment: see this https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/1950

Comment: all good, solved it, thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: add your solution as an answer and mark it as excepted.

Comment: try stopping spring `spring stop` and then  restart the server

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by:

```
touch app/admin/dashboard.rb
```

and code from:

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/generators/active_admin/install/templates/dashboard.rb